# Understanding Density Plots from Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python-3.x, density-plot

I am trying to understand the distribution of my data for a particular column.  It has close to ~1 Million records.

Here is the code that I have written to see the density plot.

```
df[ "ratio"].plot.kde(bw_method=0.1)  # Plot continuous column
```

https://wellsr.com/python/python-pandas-density-plot-from-a-dataframe/

Here is the plot that I get:

[image]

I am not clear what does `x-axis` and `y-axis` indicate?

Is `x-axis` the `ratio` values from dataframe?

What does `Density` means in `y-axis` and how it is calculated?

Do we have any such formula to derive this values in y-axis? I am more interested in deriving the values. Given the column `ratio` how can we come up with `density values`. Can someone quickly show the maths?

Answer (score 1):

If you are plotting a KDE, it means you are plotting a Probabilistic Density Function (PDF) of a random variable.

The X-Axis will be the range of values of the parameter you are plotting for. In your case, since you are plotting for **Ratio**, X-Axis will represent the range of values of your parameter **ratio**

Y-Axis on the other hand represents kernel density i.e the probability of the parameter your are plotting for.

[Read the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.kde.html)

Comment: Thank you. But I was more interested in deriving the values. Given the column `ratio` how can we come up with `density` values. Can you quickly show?

Comment: If you are particularly interested in how these values are derived, then https://www.numxl.com/support/documentation/numxl/users-guide/descriptive-statistics/kernel-density-estimation-kde-tutorial this might help you.